# Comparing Text Fields Value

Tags: android, android-studio, compare, textfield

using the Internet, Android Studio, and your current knowledge of Android app development, create an Android app project that has two (2) text fields and one (1) button. The button will compare the input from the text fields and display a response (SAME if values are the same and NOT THE SAME if they are not) if it is clicked. You may need to create a new activity for this

Comment: sample output of this activity [link1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cqmdq.png


  [link2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWD4n.png

Comment: is this an assignment task? show us what have you done

Comment: yes i haven't done yet because my teacher didn't teach me how to use Android Studio so i am self learning

Comment: you should at least get familiar with _basic IDE use_ and something to code, and give some efforts otherwise just getting done by stackOverflow won't let you learn much..

Comment: Do you atleast know how to create a project using android studio?

Comment: yes only onclick listener that i dont know and the output will appear in next page

Comment: StackOverflow assumes that you ask a question. Your text does not contain any question. The least you can do is to rewrite your text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really important to learn the basics before using **StackOverflow** is not like other *from scratch* tutorial site, you need to put some efforts first.. in case you're beginner as we all are/were someday, Google is your best friend. 
However as you've requested...

First we need to create Two `activities` one is for the input and another one for displaying result, of course you can do it in same the activity.

First `Activity`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="value 1"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="value 2"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="compare"
        android:text="Compare" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Associated `.java` file: change package name according to your need

```
package com.app.myapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }

    public void compare(View view) {
        // get the values form those two text views

        String value1 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1)).getText().toString(); // you can use global variable too.. here, I've just used the shortcut 
        String value2 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2)).getText().toString();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);

        if (value1.equals(value2)) {
            // same
            intent.putExtra("result", true);
        } else {
            intent.putExtra("result", false);
        }
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Now the `ResultActivity`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ResultActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Associated class: `.java:`

```
package com.app.myapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ResultActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

        boolean result = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("result", false);
        if (result)
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText("SAME");
        else
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText("NOT SAME");

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much bro i promise that I will learn the basics before Using this site..Thank you Again :)